# How to do text wrapping in beamercolorbox?

Tags: beamer

I am having text which is going out of the box. I want it should within box by text wrapping...how can I made this? I am using `\begin{beamercolorbox}` command to insert text within this box. How could I wrap my text within that box only?

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE. You should provide more details on your problem if you would like to get help, i.e. a minimal working example.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: It is probably text dependent, like a url or a really narrow column.  Try \sloppy or \raggedright.

Comment: Please show us a concrete example.  By default text will be set ragged right in `beamercolorbox`es.

Answer (score 1):

If the width of the `beamercolorbox` is smaller than the paperwidth, the text will wrap before it goes off the page:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=blue,fg=white}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,left,wd=\textwidth]{frametitle}
    very long text that is so long that it will eventually wrap lines if it is long enough
\end{beamercolorbox}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]